# Javascript CharCode

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that only allows numeric input:

```
function isANumber(evt) {
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))

return false;

return true;
}
```

I am trying to modify it for my Zip Code(s). The user has the ability to enter a zip in the following format 12345-6789. I am trying to add charCodes 109 and 189 to the function so the user may enter those respective keys.  This is what I have but it is not working:

```
function isAZipCode(evt) {
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode == 109 || charCode == 189) && (charCode < 48 || 
charCode   > 57))

return false;

return true;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific as to your actual problem, and what you have tried

Comment: how could that IF EVER return false?  if char was NOT 109 or 189 how could the && (charCode == 109 || charCode ==189 be true?

Comment: The top function isANumber works just fine. It only allows the user to enter numbers. I want a function that allows users to enter numbers, dash(charCode 189) and the subtract(charCode 109) only. This function is called isAZipCode and is going to be used to allow a user to enter a zip code. The user can enter a 5 digit zip code or they can enter the zip code "plus-four codes" i.e. 95448-5688.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original version works by checking the negative case, this will be easier if you modify it to check if it is one of the valid key codes and returning true if it is:

```
function isAZipCode(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || charCode == 109 || charCode == 189)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Not sure if it was intentional for your original version to return true for key codes less than 32, if you still need that behavior you can easily add it back in:

```
function isAZipCode(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode < 32 || (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || charCode == 109 || charCode == 189)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I had to change the charCode to 45 not 109 and 189.